# product of a self-adjoint operator and a bounded operator, reference request

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

Let $A$ be an unbounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space $H$ and $B$ be a bounded self-adjoint operator from $B(H)$. 
Let $A=\int \lambda dE_\lambda$ be the spectral resolution. If $B$ commutes with every $E_\lambda$, then $AB$ is self-adjoint. I have seen that some paper use this fact and I can prove that but I think there should be some references for this fact. Does anyone know such a referece?

Comment: Have you checked Reed Simon vol.1? From what I know it's the standard reference on unbounded operators et al.

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde  I had a browse on Reed-Simon, but I didn't find what I want.

Comment: @KeithMcClary it is done now